# non-existent '.' causes Parse Error after adding triples Jena ElementGroup

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am attempting to construct a new query based off of a given query (the old query--I cannot change this).

Suppose I am given a simple valid SPARQL query, `SELECT ?s WHERE{ ?s ?p ?o }`.  Let's say I make a jena query object of the above query, and get the query pattern as an ElementGroup in java as follows:

```
Query q = QueryFactory.create("SELECT ?s WHERE{ ?s ?p ?o }, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL_11);
ElementGroup oldQP = (ElementGroup)q.getQueryPattern();
```

The way I was adding new triples to the old query pattern before was using the following syntax:

```
Triple t = Triple.create(...);
oldQP.addTriplePattern(t);
```

However, when you go to create the new query object:

```
Query nq = q.cloneQuery();
nq.setQueryPattern(oldQP);
nq.setQuerySelectType();
nq.setQueryResultStar(false);
nq.addResultVar("s");
```

You end up with a query which looks like

```
SELECT ?s WHERE{
    ?s ?p ?o
    ?s2 ?p2 ?s.
}
```

because it doesn't recognize/care that the first triple doesn't end with a period when you set the object's QueryPattern.  This results in a Parse Error when the query is run...

```
Encountered " <VAR1> "?s2 "" at line 10, column 3.
Was expecting one of:
"graph" ...
"optional" ...
"minus" ...
"bind" ...
"service" ...
"let" ...
"exists" ...
"not" ...
"filter" ...
"{" ...
"}" ...
";" ...
"," ...
"." ...
```

because this clearly isn't valid SPARQL.  So, how to avoid this problem?  This problem doesn't occur if all triples have closing periods, but I can't seem to find any way to make this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code creates a query as you described, copies it, adds a triple pattern, prints it, and runs both queries.  You're right that the printed form of the query is lacking a `.` where one would normally be present.  However, as RobV [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15577515/1281433) the printing oddity doesn't have any effect on the results of the query.  If you're getting different results in your actual case, can you highlight where it differs from this?

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Triple;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.core.Var;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.syntax.ElementGroup;

public class AddTriplePattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the original query
        final String queryString = "" +
                "select * where {\n" +
                "  ?s ?p ?o .\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "";
        final Query query = QueryFactory.create( queryString );

        // Create the new query and add `?s2 ?p2 ?o2`. Print the new query
        // before and after adding the triple pattern.  Sure enough, after 
        // the modification, the pattern is printed without a `.` between the 
        // triples.  The space between the variables is also a bit bigger.
        final Query newQuery = QueryFactory.create( query );
        System.out.println( "== before ==\n"+newQuery );
        final ElementGroup eg = (ElementGroup) newQuery.getQueryPattern();
        final Triple t = new Triple( Var.alloc( "s2"), Var.alloc( "p2" ), Var.alloc( "o2" ));
        eg.addTriplePattern( t );
        newQuery.setQueryResultStar(false);
        newQuery.addResultVar( "s2" );
        System.out.println( "== after ==\n"+newQuery );

        // Create a model with a single triple [a, a, a].
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        final Resource a = model.createResource( "urn:ex:a" );
        model.add( a, a.as( Property.class ), a );

        // Run both the original query and the new query on the model.  Both
        // return the expected results.
        ResultSetFormatter.out( QueryExecutionFactory.create( query, model ).execSelect() );
        ResultSetFormatter.out( QueryExecutionFactory.create( newQuery, model ).execSelect() );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
== before ==
SELECT  *
WHERE
  { ?s ?p ?o }

== after ==
SELECT  ?s2
WHERE
  { ?s ?p ?o
    ?s2  ?p2  ?o2 .
  }

----------------------------------------
| s          | p          | o          |
========================================
| <urn:ex:a> | <urn:ex:a> | <urn:ex:a> |
----------------------------------------
--------------
| s2         |
==============
| <urn:ex:a> |
--------------
```

Comment: re: Missing .
Old bug - fixed (in development codebase at least).

Comment: @AndyS RobV's answer suggested that it's known and old, too.  I just wanted to get a complete working example here for the sake of anyone else who comes along;  now they can see what they _should_ be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely follow your question here

Where does the second query come from?  Are you calling `toString()` on the new query object in which case this could be a bug in the internal logic for printing queries.

Also what version of ARQ are you using?

Comment: System.out.println(nq.serialize()); --so yes, printing the new query object.  But doing some debugging yields that the ElementGroup itself (oldQP here) seems to look like this, so I don't believe it is the printing specifically.

Sorry for the confusion.  In essence, the problem seems to be that when you add triples to a queryPattern that looks like {?s ?p ?o} you get a query pattern that looks like {?s ?p ?o ?s2 ?p2 ?s. ?s3 ?p3 ?s2.} etc., s.t. the first triple and the next triple added aren't separated by the correct syntax (a '.' character).

I'm using the arq-2.8.5-patched-2.jar I believe.

Comment: Ok, your problem is most likely that its a really old version of ARQ, 2.8.5 is from July 2010, the current version 2.10.0 was released March 2013.  If you are able you should **really** upgrade your dependency.

Comment: Reading your question again why do you print it out as a string and parse it back in again?  Is it not possible to simply execute the new query object you've created directly thereby avoiding this issue entirely?

Comment: Sorry.  I'm not printing out as a string and parsing it again.  I am just executing the new query object I've created directly; the printed out query I gave above is just to summarize/outline the problem.  In essence, when you have a QueryPattern (Element) which looks like this: `{?s ?p ?o}` (obtained via the `Query.getQueryPattern()` method for example), and you attempt to add triples to it via the `ElementGroup.addTriplePattern(...)` method, you get a ElementGroup which looks like `{?s ?p ?p ?s2 ?p2 ?s...}`, note the non-existent period.  This causes issues when creating a new Query object.

Comment: The period is just serialization syntax and has no internal representation in code, if this is causing a problem something in your code must be turning the query into a string at some point.  Regardless my assumption is that this is a bug in the nearly 3 year old version of ARQ you are using, to reiterate please upgrade to a newer version and see if you can still reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

So I seem to have found a workaround/solution.
After debugging and looking more closely at the `ElementGroup` object created by the line

```
ElementGroup oldQP = (ElementGroup)q.getQueryPattern();
```

I noticed that it sports an ArrayList of Element objects (retrieved via the method `ElementGroup.getElements()`).  The only thing in this list before I tried to add triples (via the `ElementGroup.addTriplePattern(...)` method) was an object of Type `ElementPathBlock`.  Okay, cool.

Next, I try to add the triples via the above method, like so:

```
Triple t = Triple.create(...);
oldQP.addTriplePattern(t);
```

I notice that this adds a new `ElementTriplesBlock` to the ElementGroup's list of Elements.  It seems that this is the culprit.  So, my solution was to instead grab the last occurrence of `ElementPathBlock`, and add the triples to that object instead of adding them to the ElementGroup (thus avoiding the adding the new `ElementTriplesBlock` to the ArrayList):

```
//same as before
Query q = QueryFactory.create("SELECT ?s WHERE{ ?s ?p ?o }, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL_11);
Query nq = q.cloneQuery();
ElementGroup oldQP = (ElementGroup)q.getQueryPattern();
Triple t = Triple.create(Var.alloc("s2"), Var.alloc("p2"), Var.alloc("s));

//new
ElementPathBlock epb;
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i<oldQP.getElements().size(); i++){
    if(oldQP.getElements().get(i) instanceof ElementPathBlock){
        //...get last index of instanceof ElementPathBlock, if exists.
        index = i;
    }
}
if(index > -1){
    //...found occurence of ElementPathBlock we will add to
    epb = (ElementPathBlock) oldQP.getElements().get(index);
}else{
    //...no occurence, so make new ElementPathBlock to add
    epb = new ElementPathBlock();
}
//add Triple(s) to epb, not to oldQP
epb.addTriple(t);
//re-add (or add for first time) ElementPathBlock to the ArrayList of Elements
if(index > -1){
    oldQP.getElements().set(index, epb);
}else{
    oldQP.getElements().add(epb);
}

//same as before
nq.setQueryPattern(oldQP);
nq.setQuerySelectType();
nq.setQueryResultStar(false);
nq.addResultVar("s");
```

Looking at the oldQP now, after the above, we see that it is correctly formatted, and that the period is placed correctly:

```
{?s ?p ?o.
 ?s2 ?p2 ?s.
}
```